# Public functions returns an error due to a query inside?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting an error code and I really can't tell what the problem is here:

```
public static function createRecord($mysql, $id, $username) {

     $login = new login;

     $delete_from_sessions = $mysql->prepare("DELETE FROM com_sessions WHERE uid = ?");

     if(!$delete_from_sessions) {

         printf("Some error occured: %s\n", $mysql->error);

     } else {

         $delete_from_sessions->bind_param('s', $id);
         $delete_from_sessions->execute();

     }

     // CALL FUNCTIONS IN CLASS login
     $token = $login->createString(64);
     $serial = $login->createString(64);

     $login->createCookie($id, $username, $token, $serial);
     $login->createSession($id, $username, $token, $serial);

     $create_session = $mysql->prepare("INSERT INTO com_sessions (uid,token,serial,timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
     $create_session->bind_param('ssss', $id, $token, $serial, $posted_on);
     $create_session->execute();

}
```

So what basically is happening here is, that whenever a user fills out the login-form at index.php and their userdata is correct, the function createRecord gets called and the variables from the index's inputs are passed as arguments `$id` for the user's id (gotten through a query within the login-script) and `$username` obvously as the user's name. The query is giving me the error:

```
Some error occured: Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\session\new.session.php:101 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(28): login::createRecord(Object(mysqli), 11, 'Kevin') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\session\new.session.php on line 101
```

I've tried to take out the query and just let the functions below fire off and those ironically worked, so the variables are passed over correctly. The table name and the database connection are both correct, I've checked that multiple times. Also I've tried to free the results of my connection through `$mysql->free();`.

Comment: `$insertid` and `$posted_on` come from where?

Comment: $insertid comes from a test I've been running through, that should be $id as well. $posted_on is comming from an included configuration file on top of the PHP file. The error is coming from the first query. If I remove this, the second one gives me exactly the same error.

Comment: Search for the error message, you'll find lots of other questions that explain how to resolve it.

Comment: If the `DELETE` fails, you shouldn't try to do the `INSERT`.

Comment: Okay, I've fixed it. It seems like the query I was calling for getting the user information for the functions arguments inside the login-script wasn't fetched completly...